# how to get array key from a function

Tags: php

for example, I have the following code:

```
$pars = array('foo'=>array(1, 2, 3, 4));
function x($par){
   // how do i get array key from $par, so it will print/return 'foo'
}
x($pars['foo']);
```

how do i get the array key, when i call function `x($pars['foo'])`

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
function x($par){
  foreach ($par as $key => $value)
  {
     //you can get key here
   }
}
```

Comment: aint it will print 1, 2, 3, 4... ?

Comment: if you want key then use $key which gives (0,1,2,3),want value use $value which gives (1,2,3,4)